# Align child md-card to center of parent using angular-material?

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material

Here I have a login screen consisting of a high resolution image background, and a simple login card, which I want to center in the middle of the screen.

[image]

How can I center the card vertically and horizontally in the parent, which is a simple `div` with a background image? Here is my HTML, for which I have not made any external CSS classes yet:

```
<div style="background-image: url('./res/img/bg-2.jpg'); width: 100%; height: 100%; background-size: cover;" layout-align="center center">
    <md-card style="width: 30%; margin: 0;" layout-padding md-whiteframe="10">
        <form name="loginForm" novalidate ng-model="loginForm">
            <h2 style="margin-top: 0;">Login</h2>
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="username">
            </md-input-container>
            <md-input-container class="md-block" flex-gt-sm>
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="password">
            </md-input-container>
            <div layout="row">
                <span flex></span>
                <md-button class="md-primary md-raised" ng-click="login.login(username, password)">Login</md-button>
                <md-button ng-click="login.register()">Register</md-button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </md-card>
</div>
```

I've already fiddled with `flexboxes` and `layout-align`. Using the `layout-align` attribute of the card allowed me to center it horizontally but not vertically. Another question's answer--pertaining to `divs` only--said to style the child with `display: inline-block;` and the parent with `text-align: center;`, but this only centered the card horizontally and aligned the textfields and text to the center of the card as well (I definitely don't want that). Any help is greatly appreciated as I am very new to CSS and web-programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need both a layout and layout-align attribute on your containing div element, so:

```
layout="row" layout-align="center center"
```

See example here - http://codepen.io/parky128/pen/PGxGrX

See the examples in the docs - https://material.angularjs.org/latest/layout/alignment

Comment: Wow. That was easy. Thanks!